# How to format my histogram?

Tags: java, arrays, random, integer, histogram

So i'm really having a hard time in formatting my histogram to make it look like what it is required for us to do. I am totally lost and frustrated because I just can't make it look like the same histogram as what is ask for. Here is the link to our instruction and there is a picture there on what it is suppose to look like, I can't pit up pictures here because I don't have enough reputation but here is the link: http://www.cs.plu.edu/courses/csce144/fall2013/labs/lab07/RandomNumberTesting.html
Thanks in advance for the help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;   // to be able to read from the keyboard

public class RandomNum
{   
/* 
Method 1:
Find the maximun value in an array
*/
public static int max(int[]arr){
    int maxValue = arr[0];
    for ( int i=1; i < arr.length; i++ ){
        if (arr[i] > maxValue){
            maxValue = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return maxValue;
}
/* 
Method 2:
Compute a random integer in the range [a..b)
*/
public static int randomInteger(int a, int b){;
    int randomNum;

    randomNum = (int)(Math.random() * (b+1-a) + a);
    return randomNum;
}
/* 
Method 3:
Draw a Simple histogram of the array arr.
*/
public static void drawHistogram(int[] arr){
    for ( int i=max(arr); i>0; i--){
        System.out.print(i + "\t");
        for (int j=0; j<arr.length; j++){
            if ( arr[j] >= i){
                System.out.print("x");
            }else {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }if ( j%10 == 0 && j!=0){
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
        }System.out.println();
    }
    for (int i=0; i<=arr.length; i++){
        if ( i == 0){
            System.out.print("\t\t");
        }if ( i%10 == 0 && i != 0){
            System.out.print(i + "      ");
        }
    }System.out.println();  
}

/* 
Method 4:
Compute num random integers in the range [0..range) and put the frequency in arr[]
*/
public static void doSingleTest(int[] arr, int num, int range){
    for (int i=1; i<=num; i++){
        int random = randomInteger(0,range);
        arr[random]++;
    }
}
/* 
Method 5:
Compute num pairs of random integers in the range [0..range) and put the frequency in arr[]
*/
public static void doPairsTest(int[] arr, int num, int range){
    int rangeA = range/10;
    int rangeB = range%10;
    for (int i=1; i<=num; i++){
        int random = ((randomInteger(0,rangeA) * 10) + randomInteger(0,rangeB));
        arr[random]++;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    // declarations
    int num;
    // histogram presentation
    System.out.println("Enter the amount of pairs you want to test: ");
    num = keyboard.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[100];
    doPairsTest(arr, num, 99);
    drawHistogram( arr );

}
```

}

Comment: what output are you seeing?  Also, why do you compute your random number that way?

Comment: My histogram has too much spacing and all of my plots aren't aligned. I compute my random number that way because I need a random integer between a given range there for I have my maximum integer and minimum integer as a & b.

Comment: You random number computation is odd, just get a random number between 1 and 100, it's straightforward.  As to your histogram, it's unclear what you're drawing a histogram of?  Since your output appears to be straight text try include some actual output and what you would expect.

Comment: That method is required to get a random number between any range not just limited to 1-100. Our output should look like what I have on the link, mine is just not formatted correctly which that is what im confused about.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your code is doing, so I'll give you an example. Say you have 20 values

```
int[] array = new int[20];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    array[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 50 + 1);  // random 1 to 50
}
```

First I'd find the max value;

```
int max = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if (array[i] > max) {
        max = array[i];
    }
}
```

Then you can use the `max` value and the `array.length` to loop the output.

```
for (int i = max; i >= 0; i--){  // start at the max number to print out
    // print i
    System.out.printf("%-4f", i);

    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; i++){  // remember, you're printing sideways
        if (array[j] >= i) { 
            System.out.print("x");
        } else {
            System.out.print(" "); // if condition not met, print space
        }
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

**Edit: with method**

```
public static void histogram(int[] array){
    int max = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if (array[i] > max) {
            max = array[i];
        }
    }

    for (int i = max; i >= 0; i--){  // start at the max number to print out
        // print i
        System.out.printf("%-4f", i);

        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; i++){  // remember, you're printing sideways
            if (array[j] >= i) { 
                System.out.print("x");
            } else {
                System.out.print(" "); // if condition not met, print space
            }
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Call in `main` method

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    // your code to get your array goes here.
    int[] yourArray = // whatever your array is

    histogram(yourArray);
    // this is all you need to do, just call my method with your array
}
```

Comment: My code is making a histogram of the frequency in num amount of times of random pairs generated from a given range. A given example and explanation is in the link. Theres a picture there on what it should look like but mine is somewhat looks like that but not formatted the way it has it in the instruction

Comment: Regardless of how you're getting your values, they're still going into an array right? instead of using my array, just use yours with the rest of my code and see if its the output you're look for.

Comment: Where did you want me to put your code, where am I suppose to adjust things, which methods?

Comment: Don't mess around with your code. Just open up a new java file and put my edit code in there, plus whatever code you have to get your array.  Then test it out. If it looks the way you want, then just fix your code accordingly.

Comment: Actually, I didn't see you code completely. You can just put my method into your file, and just call from your `main`

Comment: im getting an error with this new histogram method:

X:\csce144\labs\lab07> java RandomNumTest
Enter the amount of pairs you want to test: 
10000
Process java exited with code 1
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.Integer
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)

Comment: If you check out this link here is what im trying to get, if it makes it easier for you to understand. http://www.cs.plu.edu/courses/csce144/fall2013/labs/lab07/RandomNumberTesting.html